# show elements with style display:none !important (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, show

As said in [jQuery documentation --- .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

> Note: If using **!important** in your styles, such as **display: none
>   !important**, it is necessary to override the style using
>   **.css('display', 'block !important')** should you wish for .show() to
>   function correctly.

But it seems the style cannot be overridden and the element cannot be shown. Am I doing anything wrong here?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FF3mc/)

Comment: Looks like a bug, at least according to the documentation.

Comment: !important overrules the subsequent styling. So your !important in the CSS is applied first and it overrules the styling you set with the javascript.

Answer (score 6):

When you use the `attr` it can work. jQueries `.css()` and `.prop()` both won't work

In this fiddle with `attr` remove the `!important` from the javascript and you will see how the CSS `!important` overrules even the inline styling.

[your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FF3mc/3/)

Comment: well, then I have to first make sure there's no style attr defined for the element. otherwise it'll wipe all other styles. http://jsfiddle.net/FF3mc/5/ doesn't seem to be the perfect solution.

Comment: Agree, but that can be solved easily [http://jsfiddle.net/FF3mc/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/FF3mc/6/)

Comment: when an element is being toggled several times, it'll make the generated source larger and larger, results in something like `disply: block !important; display: none !important; disply: block !important; display: none !important;...`

Comment: Just being picky, but it should probably be `;display: block !important` since you can't be 100% sure there's a `;` at the end of the existing rules :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can do it with classes (so all your CSS is in the CSS files themselves, and not being directly altered by javascript): http://jsfiddle.net/FF3mc/4/

Comment: Good point. It looks much cleaner. However I found when I need performance (webkit animations) it is must faster to change the inline styling than applying classes and let the browser find out what css to apply

Comment: Yeah, I guess sometimes that is true. Problem with setting the style attribute is that you might overwrite what's already there though!

Comment: And well, ideally, `!important` should be avoided as much as possible! :)

Comment: Second that! Classes is better for cleanliness, inline is better for performance (and takes a bit more work)

Comment: with a big ajax project, there might be a lot of styles defined with !important. and I have to write another class for each of them. seems like I'm doing some extra work which should have been avoided.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.classname').attr("style", "display: block !important");
```

We can't use .css() here as it does not support !important.